# How can I get the Sound Indicator to show the track's file name?

Tags: indicator-sound

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I like how the sound indicator takes control of Amarok, but I would like to change the display to only show the file name of the song that is playing, since my Artist and Title tags are foreign, and I really don't care for the album image either. It would also be nice to get Amarok's titlebar to show the file name of the song, but my main concern right now is the Sound Indicator.

So, how do I get all the unnecessary stuff off of my sound indicator?

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Here's a screenshot to help explain what I'm having an issue with. I would like the sound indicator to show the same thing as Amarok's playlist entry. Screenshot:

[image: Sound Issue Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out through Google searches :)

I installed EasyTAG and used it to auto-fill all the tracks using the song's file name. Now, the sound indicator shows the same information as the file names :) This also fixed the title bar entry in Amarok.

The code to install EasyTAG is:

```
sudo apt-get install easytag
```